# How to protect a CD without a case

Tags: technology

I am currently using a plastic freezer bag with a bubble envelope. Any other better hacks to store CD until I get a CD case?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal case would be using this

[image: CD pouch]

But if you are waiting for one such case(I hope by *case*, you meant this one itself), you could use this plastic cover in which blank CD's come to market:
[image: Blank CD case]

You could easily get them at nearby shop that sells these, as they are felt as waste.

Answer (score 0):

My own preference for this is olefin -- sold as the commercial product Tyvek in the USA, it's a slightly slippery material that looks felted, but is thin and extremely strong.  It's available in office supply stores as express envelopes, or in home improvement stores as house wrap.  It cuts with scissors, glues with hot glue or super glue, and can be easily fabricated into a CD sleeve by following the pattern for a paper one.  It's less abrasive than paper, so less prone to wear and scratches on the disk.